# Help understanding the definition of derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $ f $ be **defined** and real-valued on $[a,b]$. For any $ x\in [a,b] $ form the quotient

$$ \phi(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\;,\;\; (\;a<t<b\;,\;\; \text{such that}\;\;t\neq x\; )$$

and define $ f'(x)=lim(\phi(t)) $ as $ t\rightarrow x $.

First, what exactly does it mean for $f $ to be **defined** on an interval?

Second, what is **$ t $** exactly? Is it a sequence of points approaching $ x $? Is it just a point in the interval $ [a,b] $? I am having trouble understanding $ t$'s relationship to $ x $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means for any $x\in [a,b]$ you know what $f(x)$ is.
2. $t$ can be understood as a sequence converging to $x$.

You can understand $t$ as $x+\Delta x$, i.e. a small change of $x$. Then $t\to x$ means $\Delta x\to 0$

As a side remark, I would understand the derivative as a linear approximation of a function locally. Perhaps you could see why this is from the usual definition.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20909/discussion-on-answer-by-qidi-help-understanding-the-definition-of-derivative).